# React-final-form-array how to rerender form based on new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, react-final-form

I'm using `react-final-form-arrays` to build a dynamic field system, so far the scenario would be like this:

1. User clicks on button to open the editor modal (Add/Remove custom field using `react-final-form-array`. Once done, click Save and it will update the primary form.

The primary form is also using `react-final-form-array` to loop through the fields and render, without the Add/Remove button added.

I've tried to put a very sample from here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-arrays-wbhgq?fontsize=14

In that sample, `<Form1 />` is actually the editor form. Once submitted, `<Form2 />` will render with new fields updated.

If I reload the page, it works but of course this is not what it should have been.

What should I change to make my `<Form2 />` update ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but the main idea is to create a store for the initialValues using useState or state of class component

```
  const App = () => {
    const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState();

    return (
      <Styles>
        <Form1 onSubmit={setInitialValues} />
        <Form2 initialValues={initialValues} />
      </Styles>
    );
};
```

If it is not what you want to achieve explain it in details

Comment: `react-final-form` uses its own internal state management so there's no need to have an external state like your suggestion, usually I just pass data directly to `initialValues` prop and it works. But here in this case the fields are dynamic based on an external configuration modal. I've tried to log the data before passing it to <Form />, and it's correct with the updated ones but on the UI, it wont re-render with update fields ;(

Comment: Describe in details the flow. User opens the modal where can add fields like form1 and then what? I know final-form works. My example base on what I understood from your question. In your example, the store changes its value but the component doesn't know that it needs to rerender. If you want to initialize the form2 with data from from1 this is the simplest solution

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I've managed to resolve the issue, it was my mistake of setting `keepDirtyOnReinitialize` to `true`

Comment: Hi. Author here. This answer is correct if the OP really wants to have a second confirmation form. This is how the [Wizard Example](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/wizard) works.